# Whats the best ranking system for pool players with different numbers of games played?

Tags: statistics

My group has a spreadsheet keeping track of each game (who won and who lost), individual records, and individual winning percentages. Since everyone might play a different number of games from everyone else, it seems unfair to rank by winning percentage (8 wins and 1 loss gets you second place if someone else has 1 win and 0 losses). Whats a simple way to implement a fair ranking system in google sheets.

Comment: ELO and Trueskill are both good, depending on your requirements.

Comment: No matter what you try, comparing a person with a single win against anyone other than the one person he played is going to be dicey.